# Django 1.7 Dashes in URL

Tags: python, django

I feel like I'm tripping. I am trying to add a **url with-dashes**. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong using non-classbased views. I don't think I can render a definition like blog_post.as_view() since it doesn't have it.

Does anyone see an obvious error?

**Error Message:**

```
Reverse for 'blog_post' with arguments '(u'i-prefer-debian',)' 
and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['blog/$post/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'blog_post', name="blog_post"),
```

**views.py**

```
def blog_post(request, slug):
    print 1  # To see if it gets hit
    context = {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Posts, slug=slug)
    }

    return render(request, 'blog_post.html', context)
```

**blog_list.html**

```
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div>
            <a href="{% url 'blog_post' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
            {{ post.created_at }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you post the `urls.py` from which you include the one you are showing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems comes from the `urls.py` file where you include the `urls.py` you are showing.

It looks like you did:

```
url(r'^blog/$', include('blog.urls'))
```

You need to drop the `$` ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)).

Comment: Man you understand life, thanks I have been looking in the wrong place all this time